# Git .gitignore not working on artisan file from laravel

Tags: git, laravel, gitignore, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to add artisan file from laravel installation in .gitignore. Not working. It is possible that GIT to mistake artisan [file] with a directory? There is no extension on artisan file and this can be a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 2):

I really can't find a reason for not adding the artisan bash script to the repository, but here is a tip on how to ignore it:

Your .gitignore is working, but it still tracks the files because they were already in the index.

To stop this you have to do : `git rm --cached artisan`

So in your `.gitignore` add: `artisan` in a new line

When you commit the artisan file will be removed from your git repository and the following commits will ignore the artisan file.

Answer (score 0):

**This question qualifies as a duplicate and would get merged.**

I have had the trouble with gitignore too many times, I would suggest you to follow the following steps :

---

1. Make sure whether this is your first commit or earlier these files were added and thus have become cached.

   2. If yes, then git rm -r --cached . and git add . (do not miss the dot)
2. If it still isn't working, open file menu in notepad
3. Go to File -> Save as
4. Change the encoding to ANSI. (Some answers mistakenly say UTF-8 , but it doesn't work and wastes time needlessly)

   6. Again git rm -r --cached . and git add . (do not miss the dot)